Finding the closest power of 2 to given number?
I'm trying to figure out a singular arithmetic solution formula for a certain solution of a problem, a part of which requires finding $l$, which in this case is the given number $n$ minus the closest power of 2 that's smaller than $n$ itself, I call it $a$.
For example, if $n = 36$ then $a$ would be equal to $32$ and $l$ would be equal to $4$.
I tried doing a sawtooth graph, putting $n$ in which would result in the number I need to multiply $n$ by to get $a$. It looked like this.

$p(n) = (⌊√n⌋  - √n) / 2 + 1$

This function is supposed to give me a number between $1$ and $0.5 + $ (because if the number is 0.5, then given for example $32$ it'd go back to $16$, and so on and so forth. That's why it never can't be 0.5). However, the values of $y = 1$ were not always on the powers of 2. Actually, it represented every second power of 2. (a.k.a. $2, 16, 64, 258$ etc.) Is there a way to fix this, or, maybe, figure out a better formula for finding $a$?

It looks to me like you could more easily use logarithms: suppose that $n=2^{r+\epsilon}$ then $r+\epsilon = \frac {\log n}{\log 2}$ (taking logarithms to any convenient base)

$$2^{\lfloor\log_2(a)\rfloor}\le a<2^{\lfloor\log_2(a)\rfloor+1}.$$

Compare to the problem of finding the nearest power of ten to a number.  Just turn all digits in the base-10 representation of the number into zeroes apart from the first... maybe decide to round in one direction rather than the other based on preferences.  Recognize that this is in fact no different than your stated problem... just talk about base-2 instead.

Wow, 2 different ways to explain it. This is fascinating. Express it as log base 2 (which I was about to do), or map to base 10 rounding, which to the student is trivial. That's how Feynman would explain it. If I could live again, I'd explore education theory.

The closest power of $2$ to the given number $a$ is $2^k$ where
$$k=\left\lfloor\log_2a\right\rfloor+\epsilon\left(1+\left\{\log_2a\right\}-\log_23\right)$$
where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$, and the function $\epsilon(x)$ is defined as:
$$\epsilon (x) :=\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if } x < 0, \\
1 & \text{if } x > 0, \\
\text{0 or 1} & \text{if } x = 0. \end{cases}$$
Note that $\epsilon(0)$ can take either value $0$ or $1$ since in this case $a$ is exactly at the mid-point of two consecutive powers of $2$.

How does it work?
Let $a\in[2^{n},2^{n+1})$ or $\log_2a\in[n,n+1)$. The number that lies exactly at the mid-point of $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$ is $(2^{n-1}+2^n)$. So, if
$$a<2^{n}+2^{n-1}$$
$$\iff \log_2a<n+\log_2(3/2)$$
$$\iff\{\log_2a\}<\log_2(3/2)$$ then the closest power of $2$ is $2^n=2^{\lfloor\log_2a\rfloor}$. If the inequalities are flipped, $2^{n+1}=2^{\lfloor\log_2a\rfloor+1}$ is the closest power of $2$.
So, we can define a function $\epsilon(x)$ for argument $x$ and express it as above.

So what is ε(0)?

@Divide1918 $\epsilon(0)$ means $a$ is exactly between the two consecutive powers of $2$. So, $\epsilon(0)=0$ or $1$.

So does ε(0)=0 or ε(0)=1?

@Divide1918 You can take either $0$ or $1$. For example, both $32$ and $64$ are the closest powers of $2$ to $48$.

@Divide1918 According to the definition of a function, $\epsilon (x)$ is undefined at $x=0$. In such cases, $a$ is at the mid-point of two consecutive powers of $2$. So, we can take both values $0$ and $1$ as only one power of $2$ is strictly not the solution.

This seems really cool. Why does it work?

@BenjaminWang I added it to my answer. Please read it. Thank you for the comment.

I think that this won't satisfy what I need, or maybe I misunderstood. I need the closest power of 2 that I get to always be smaller than n, the input number. I don't need just closest.

@Stepanchicko The closest power of $2$ may be greater than the input number $n$ or $a$. For example, $56$ is closer to $64$ compared to $32$.

@PustamRaut Exactly, and I don't need that. I need the answer (that is a power of 2) to be smaller than n. Even if the number is 56, I need the answer to be 32. That's why I asked the question in the first place.

@Stepanchicko Then it is just $2^{\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor}$.

@PustamRaut It was that easy? Oh well. Thanks.

@Stepanchicko It appears in the least common multiple of the first $n$ natural numbers. $\Large \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots,n)=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{\pi(n)}p_k^{\left\lfloor\log_{p_k}n\right\rfloor}$, which is the product of the highest prime powers less than or equal to $n$.

@PustamRaut I was trying to graph the Josephus problem actually. Anyway, you helped me out a ton. Thank you very much, I think I need to learn how logarithms work better.

"Exactly, and I don't need that." Then don't use word closest, because it means... the closest.
